# How can I repeat a pattern image to create a background in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm building a simple ReactNative app for iOS and I'm trying to add a background image. It seems like there is no backgroundImage tag, and while I did manage to show the image on the page once, I can't repeat it throughout the page like you can with CSS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat background image like CSS in React Native. But, You can achieve it by iterating the image like

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

var {
  Image
} = React;

var RepeatImage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    var images = [],  
    imgWidth = 7,
    winWidth =Dimensions.get('window').width;

    for(var i=0;i<Math.ceil(winWidth / imgWidth);i++){
        images.push((
           <Image source={{uri: 'http://xxx.png'}} style={} />
        ))
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
        {
         images.map(function(img,i){
         return img;
         })
        }
        </View>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Is that viable memory wise?

Comment: Actually you can

Comment: But would this show only single line or repeated images? this looks like only a partial solution, it wouldn't really do same as `repeat` mode on iOs.

Comment: bad solution don't use this

Answer (score 30):

## iOS

Images on **iOS** now include a `repeat` [resizeMode property](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode).

Use it like so:

```
<Image
    src={/* whatever your source is */}
    resizeMode="repeat"
/>
```

## Android

### June 2018 Update:

Starting from react-native 0.56 Android Images also support the `repeat` prop. (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0459e4ffaadb161598ce1a5b14c08d49a9257c9c)

### Before June 2018:

<s>On **Android** the `repeat` property does NOT work so:
you'll have to use something like [Shiraman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38107886/1658268)</s>

#### External lib:

There's now this great project called [react-native-bgimage](https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-bgimage) (created by [Alex Melanchenko](https://github.com/alexnd)) which works well:

Here's how I use it:

```
import RepeatingPattern from 'react-native-bgimage';

<RepeatingPattern
    drawable="block_pattern"
    style={{
      height: 45,
    }}
/>
```

and then I add a pattern png file in `android/app/src/main/res/drawable/block_pattern.png`

Comment: Yep, it says it in the answer - also the person asking the question specifically asked for iOS. 
That being said, on Android you'll have to do something similar to what Sriraman suggests.

Comment: You should include a sample of code, it is not included in the documentation and people might take a considerable amount of time to implement this.

Comment: What are you talking about @thibautnoah it IS included in the documentation on the link I posted.

Comment: @SudoPlz there is no sample whatsoever in facebook documentation

Comment: I'm confused @thibautnoah what kind of sample are you looking for?
You use it like so:

`<Image source={{uri: 'http://xxx.png'}} resizeMode="repeat" />` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what i was talking about. Good thing i am not alone at the office so i didn't actually need a code sample, but shame on facebook for not giving one.

Answer (score 11):

Despite that this question is pretty old I would like to put my two cents in. It is also can be done via `<ImageBackground>` component ([reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#background-image-via-nesting)).

Example:

```
<ImageBackground source={require('./path/to/image.png')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'repeat'}}>
  // Your inside content goes here
</ImageBackground>
```

Don't forget to import component in the beginning of file, e.g. `import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';`

Comment: one caveat here is, we cannot use .svg images in current version of RN (v0.62.2)

Comment: We can use svg file! @GaleelBhasha use react native svg

Answer (score 5):

I would like to extend Sriraman answer. To make the repeated images as the background, you need to take an addtional step of adding a new view and making its position absolute and background transparent, then adding all the other components inside of it.

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');

var {
  Image
} = React;

var RepeatImage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
    var images = [],  
    imgWidth = 7,
    winWidth =Dimensions.get('window').width;

    for(var i=0;i<Math.ceil(winWidth / imgWidth);i++){
        images.push((
           <Image source={{uri: 'http://xxx.png'}} style={} />
        ))
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row'}}>
        {
         images.map(function(img,i){
         return img;
         })
        }
          <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}}>
              {/*Place all you compoents inside this view*/}
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What if I don't know the dimension of the view that this background is for?

Comment: ^ this and it only works horizontally not vertically. I guess we can't have both.

Comment: @Aakash what exactly we are doing by position absolute top , bottom , left , right 0 ??