# Background image fixed and the text scrolling is Infinite in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image, web-frontend

I was trying to build a chat window in which I have a background image and I have fixed the minimum height of the screen as '100vh' I just wanted to make the background image fixed on an infinite scroll of text the code is
  (as I was using React jS so the CSS design is in the variable **messageContainer** )

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Header from './Header';
import { UserNameContext, RoomNameContext } from '../UserContext'
import background from './chatBackground.jpg';
export default function ChatRoom() {

    /*const { userName, setUserName } = useContext(UserNameContext);
    const { roomName, setRoomName } = useContext(RoomNameContext);*/
    const messageContainer = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
        backgroundRepeat: 'repeat-y',
        backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
        backgroundPosition: 'center center',
        minHeight:'100vh',

    }
    return (

        <div>
            <Header />
            <div style={messageContainer}>
                <div className="opponent msg">
                    <p>Hey! how are you please let me know how is it going</p>
                </div>
                <div className="own msg">
                    <p className="text">Hey! how are you please let me
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="opponent msg">
                    <p>Hey! how are you please let me know how is it going</p>
                </div>
                <div className="own msg">
                    <p className="text">Hey! how are you please let me
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div className="opponent msg">
                    <p>Hey! how are you please let me know how is it going</p>
                </div><div className="opponent msg">
                    <p>Hey! how are you please let me know how is it going</p>
                </div>
                <div className="own msg">
                    <p className="text">Hey! how are you please let me
                    </p>
                </div><div className="own msg">
                    <p className="text">Hey! how are you please let me
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: The background image disappears after a certain amount of scroll this is the error image]
[image: I want the background image to never end I want like this]

My message box CSS code is

```
    .opponent
    {
      background-color: #007bff;
      max-width: 80%;
      color:white;
      float:left;
      margin-left: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .own
    {
      background-color: #c3c7cc;
      max-width: 80%;
      color:black;
      float:right;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      margin-right: 5px;
      text-align: right; 
    }
    .msg{
      margin-top: 1rem;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding:2vh;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107439/how-can-i-repeat-a-pattern-image-to-create-a-background-in-react-native)?

Comment: can you try adding `backgroundSize: cover`?

Comment: @WoAiNii actually I am new to React so I am unable to implement that

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon Yes I have tried like that not working

Comment: try changing `minHeight` to `height: 100vh` and if it doesn't work try reducing the height and see if you get anything to work.

Comment: @SpiritOfDragon done almost all the CSS possibilities nothing useful.

Comment: maybe header is position fixed? add some padding to the container. However, the right way to do is the way @WoAiNii mention above!